# Javascript modal close issues

Tags: javascript, html, function, modal-dialog

So I have a modal that opens when a UI icon is clicked and for some reason the modal will not close in any browser other than IE. Is there a simpler way of doing this? Or any browser specification I can add?

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Click function for modal -->
$(ui).click(function modal() {
    el = document.getElementById("modal");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible")?"hidden":"visible";
});
```

```
<div id="modal" class="modal" draggable="true">
<div>
<h3 style="text-decoration: underline"> Summary Report Table </h3>
    <table id="summary">
        <tr>
            <th> Trans Count </th>
            <th> Trans Amt </th>
            <th> Match Count </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> 300 </td>
            <td> $200,000 </td>
            <td> 4 </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <a href='#' onClick='modal()'>Close</a>
</div>
```

Not sure why, but it will not let me indent or return on my code. Apologize for the poor readability.

Comment: You are already using jquery.  Is there a reason you are not using jQuery dialog?  OR, you can replace the entire contents of your function with this:  '$("#modal").toggle();'

Comment: @DavidFleeman I think that jQuery dialog needs jQuery UI. Maybe asker doesn't want it.

Comment: I am using jQuery but the jQuery click functions are not working. I am also using jQuery UI

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following (assuming you're using jquery):

```
$(ui).click(function () {
    $("#modal").toggle();
});
```

The above code will toggle the modal (show it if it's hidden, or hide it if it's already visible) when you click the "ui" button

Comment: I tried that and for some reason it eliminated my click functionality all together

Comment: can you clarify exactly what the "ui" is?

Comment: You also have a div tag that you're not closing (the second one).

Comment: Azad "UI" specifies the nodes in Vivagraph.js (this is the library I am using) and I close it later on in the code, I should have close that for clarification.

Comment: Can you possibly add some more of your code. Just to see if you're making any minor mistakes that are breaking the whole program. Also I don't know if you know this, but you can use console.log() to debug programs.